# JavaMe application support

Tags: java-me, mobile-application, nokia-s40

I need to develop a JavaME application to target low end cell phones. But the target here is to make one app that works for most of the phones. But on the Nokia developers site, i can see that they have different SDKs for different categories of phones. That would mean that other phone makers have their own SDKs? Cant i make a universal JavaME app that all Java enabled phones can install? if not all, maybe a majority. I have no experience with JavaME so please be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differend SDKs on Nokia developers site is for different MIDP versions, not really for different phones. Well, actually the new one (Asha 1.0) is the same MIDP version of the 2.0 SDK. But, if you want to develop for any J2ME device, you really should use MIDP version 1.0 (any Nokia SDK delivers that, even the newest one).

But beware, you will need to cope with a lot of restrictions, and basically use standard components, since their user experience is supported by all kinds of devices: (fulltouch, touch & type and qwerty phones).

Comment: I think it's fair to say that no one uses MIDP1.0 phones anymore. Target MIDP 2.0 CLDC 1.1 and you'll be fine.
Device specific SDK's can be handy, especially if you're developing an app that uses some special functionality of that device.
Personally I've only ever used the default emulator myself, because I've never had to use any special functions of a certain device. And then I make sure I test on lots of different REAL devices.